# Trying to select CSS that appears to change frequently?

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script for a google product (https://www.google.com/flights/)

Basically, I'm trying to modify the CSS so that the map can be displayed larger.  I created a very basic greasemonkey script that can do this very easily if I can identify the CSS class.  In my script it is ".GN1QYMKH3B" which worked for a week but then this week it appears that all of the classes have changed.  Is google generating these classes to prevent manipulation and if so, is there a way to navigate the DOM to select the correct CSS?

Comment: Have you thought about looking at id that stay the same consistently then navigating those to elements you are trying to change. Ive never used greasemonkey but maybe that will help.

Comment: you can use IDs and other partial attributes that might not change, like iframe[src*='update'], [aria-hidden="true"], img[width='320'], etc. you can then use stuff like nextElementSibling, children[2], and other relative navigation to arrive at the right node.

Comment: Is there a way to select an element by background color?  The map class has background-color of #E5E3DF.  Is there any way to use this (or a jQuery selector) based on background color?